# What is the default "effective" titlestring?

Tags: options

Is the effective default value for `titlestring` documented somewhere?  By effective, I mean the one that displays `$(basename) ($(dirname)) (m of n) - GVIM1` or `... ((m) of n)`, even though `titlestring` is "actually" empty (so I guess it's some hard-coded default somewhere).

The reason is that I would like to change the `m of n` part to use the buffer list rather than the argument list (the latter being quite confusing when one frequently uses e.g. :bd), but keep the rest.  Yes, I could probably work it out by fully reading the docs on `statusline`, but I'm trying to avoid that...

Comment: this question could be read in two ways: "what is the exact format of the default title?," which would have to be an explanation of the c code, or "which titlestring most closely emulates vim's default title formatting?"

Comment: I am looking for something that can be emulated by setting titlestring (but with some modifications), so the second interpretation is correct.

Comment: The C code is [here in `maketitle` function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/0a016671b96a/src/buffer.c#L3920-L4021). I'll try and write a VimL version of it.